# Laravel 5.5: Controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Coming from CodeIgniter, I decided that it's time for something new and went for Laravel. I love the syntax of the framework and how clean it is, however, I am overwhelmed by how complicated simple things seem to be. I have a controller and want to link to a function in said controller. Whatever I do, I keep getting this error:

```
   ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\TasksController does not exist
```

I have Googled this issue but I just can't seem to figure it out. It seems like I got everything right but then again, I'm completely new to this framework so I don't really know. I have a namespace, a route and all of that stuff. Anyway, here is my code:

The link

```
<a class="nav-link" href="<?= url('tasks') ?>">Tasks</a>
```

My route in routes.php

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

TasksController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->get();
        return view('tasks', ['tasks' => $tasks]);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any answers and if you need more information, please say so.

Comment: Try `Route::resource('tasks', 'Controller\TasksController');` because your full class namespace/name is `App\Http\Controllers\Controller\TasksController`. Or remove the extra `Controller` from your namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the extra namespace did it. I knew I had it wrong there somewhere... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are using default Laravel installation, the current directory of controllers does not exist.

Try changing

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

to

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

in your TasksController.php file

Comment: Yup, thanks! aynber already made this suggestion. Can't believe it was that simple. I guess that's what programming at the end of the night does to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace (in controller file) is `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` and should be `App\Http\Controllers`.